# Adding a time delay to a JQuery function?

Tags: jquery, function, delay, jscrollpane

I have the scrollplane script:

```
$(function()
{
    $('#resume').jScrollPane(
      {
     autoReinitialise: true
  }
      );
});
```

Which allows my overflow: auto container to full load and be totally displayed when scrolled.  Unfortunately this give me text jitters in Chrome but not Firefox.  I'm guessing it's on each "reinitiate."

[jitters in Chrome browser](http://test1.chuprinastudios.com/resume2.php)

I'm thinking of taking out "autoreinitialize" and add a "delay()" on firing the function allowing all the images/fonts to download, not changing the size of the container would do the same thing.  I just don't know how to implement it and delay the function from firing.

Any help and/or guidance gratefully accepted.

PChuprina

Comment: What do you mean "text jitters"? The page you linked seems to work fine for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

search for window.setTimeout. using that you can delay execution of some piece of code.

Comment: Thankyou.  I just do not know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

setTimout is ok too, but JQuery has [delay() function](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Be aware, although I never had problems with delay():

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Good luck & happy coding

Comment: Thank You.  I just don't know how to successfully implement it.
$('#resume').delay(100).queue(function(next) { $(this).jScrollPane(); next(); }); Breaks the jScrollpane function.
PChuprina